# Validar archivo CSV con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

l,Tengo el siguiente formato de CSV, el cual quiero validar, son 2 columnas separadas por coma:
CSV CORRECTO

> ```
> numero documento,Descripcion
> 4,Entidad 5 deudas prueba Importada
> 5,entidad 4 deudas prueba importada
> 151,Entidad Prueba 6
> 156,Entidad Prueba 7
> 157,Entidad Prueba 8
> ```

CSV INCORRECTO

> ```
> numero documento;Descripcion
> 4;Entidad 5 deudas prueba Importada
> 5;entidad 4 deudas prueba importada
> 151;Entidad Prueba 6
> 156;Entidad Prueba 7
> 157;Entidad Prueba 8
> ```

Necesito notificar si el CSV está en formato correcto(dos filas separadas por coma), pueden ser muchos registros.

Imagino que con un patrón, pero no logro imaginarlo.

Comment: Para mí el csv es válido aún así si una sola línea tiene simplemente una `,`. Especifica por favor cómo y qué es lo que deseas validar, y qué es lo que has intentado por favor. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: quiero validar para ese formato el CSV, decir si es corecto o no